# Using XSLT/Saxon how do I get the desired content type when using the document function to access a webservice?

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, saxon

I use Saxon (version 9.1.0.7J from Saxonica) to transform an XML file and use the document function to insert XML into the result document from a webservice. This webservice can generate HTML, XML and JSON which is controlled using the Accept header. For some reason Saxon sends the following accept header: `text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2` so the webservice does not give me XML but HTML instead. I use `<xsl:output method="xml" media-type="text/xml" />` in my XSL stylesheet but that does not seem to have any effect. Anyone knows how I can get Saxon to emit a `Accept: text/xml` header for document() calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon by default does whatever Java does when you call URL.openConnection(). If you want it to do something different, you will need to write your own URIResolver. (Or I believe you can influence it with Java system property settings, but I don't know the detail on that, and in any case system properties are a clumsy mechanism because they affect everything that happens in the JVM instance.)

Having said that, I've no idea (without doing some research) where this Accept header comes from.

Comment: The problem with the `URIResolver` approach is that sometimes the URI itself does not carry (enough) information to be able to choose the content type.

Say `http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=select+*+where+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+%7D+LIMIT+1` requires `Accept: application/sparql-results+xml` while `http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=construct+%7B+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+%7D+where+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+%7D+LIMIT+1` requires `application/rdf+xml`. The only difference is the query string, which I don't want to parse in `URIResolver`.

I think an explicit hint such as `saxon:accept=` would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: There's work going on in EXPath to define a full set of HTTP request functions as an extension library for XPath. When that's done, we're likely to implement it. Can I suggest that you review the current proposals and comment on them? https://github.com/expath/expath-cg/tree/master/specs/http-client